# Issue with export-excel in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

All

I'm having some strange issue in powershell when exporting get-aduser output.

## My script working

```
#Open Excel Object

$ExcelObj = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$ExcelObj.visible=$False

$CardUsers = Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter{(extensionAttribute9 -like "*") }
$CardUsers | Export-Excel 'C:\Users(username)\Downloads\employee_list.xlsx' -WorksheetName "Current Employee" -MoveAfter "All Employee" -AutoSize
```

=> Get-ADUser info is being saved as worksheet name "Current Employee" after "All Employee" worksheet. This is expected result.

## My script not working

```
#Open Excel Object

$ExcelObj = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$ExcelObj.visible=$False
$SOURCE_DATA = $env:USERPROFILE + "\Downloads"

$CardUsers = Get-ADUser -Properties * -Filter{(extensionAttribute9 -like "*") }
$CardUsers | Export-Excel '$SOURCE_DATA\employee_list.xlsx' -WorksheetName "Current Employee" -MoveAfter "All Employee" -AutoSize
```

=>Getting the following error message.

WARNING: Can't find worksheet 'All Employee'; worsheet 'Current Employee' will not be moved.

---

Only difference is that I was trying to use $env:USERPROFILE, and it's pointing the same location basically. But, not sure why the error is occurring. Anyone has clue? Please advise. I really appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using ComObject if you have ImportExcel installed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a variable in a string you need to use double quotes. Edit your last line to this:

```
$CardUsers | Export-Excel "$($SOURCE_DATA)\employee_list.xlsx" -WorksheetName "Current Employee" -MoveAfter "All Employee" -AutoSize
```

Single quotes interpret the $ sign as text and not as a variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. Your solution resolved the issue I've faced. One more question. Could you please explain the reason why the correct code is "$($SOURCE_DATA)\employee_list.xlsx" not "$SOURCE_DATA\employee_list.xlsx"

Comment: You're welcome! There is no "correct", in your case both variations work. The difference is that the brackets in `$($SOURCE_DATA)` define where the variable starts and ends. If you have a variable with properties (for example `$($SOURCE_DATA.MyProperty)`) you have to use this style, otherwise everything behind the dot will be interpreted as string. Check this article for more information: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.2#variable-substitution (chapter Variable substitution & Command substitution)

Comment: I do understand your point. Thank you very much for your excellent explanation. Highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @bacchus21 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.